# Error deploying java app on heroku

Tags: java, heroku

I'm on windows and this is my first java deploy on heroku and I'm quite new to heroku.
Following [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java#deploy-the-app) guide and when I want to visit the app url I get this screen: [image]
Here it is my heroku logs:

```
C:\Users\Luca\workspace\ScacchiCopia>heroku open
Opening gentle-mesa-xxxx... done

C:\Users\Luca\workspace\ScacchiCopia>heroku logs
2015-08-05T14:23:46.657148+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window
.java:536)
2015-08-05T14:23:46.657236+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.j
ava:420)
2015-08-05T14:23:46.657323+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.j
ava:385)
2015-08-05T14:23:46.657416+00:00 app[web.1]:    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFr
ame.java:189)
2015-08-05T14:23:46.657517+00:00 app[web.1]:    at ChessBoard_SO.<init>(ChessBoa
rd_SO.java:11)
2015-08-05T14:23:46.657610+00:00 app[web.1]:    at ChessBoard_SO.main(ChessBoard
_SO.java:395)
2015-08-05T14:23:47.551943+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2015-08-05T14:23:47.538227+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-08-05T20:05:21.031881+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2015-08-05T20:05:26.099109+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `j
ava -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* ChessBoard_SO`
2015-08-05T20:05:28.319274+00:00 app[web.1]: Exception in thread "main" java.awt
.HeadlessException:
2015-08-05T20:05:28.319410+00:00 app[web.1]: No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, bu
t this program performed an operation which requires it.

2015-08-06T07:50:21.301050+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `j
ava -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* ChessBoard_SO`
2015-08-07T07:02:28.708591+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=gentle-mesa-8436.herokuapp.com request_id=9daeabf
a-1dd3-4277-8833-785bdae9af93 fwd="79.41.230.143" dyno= connect= service= status
=503 bytes=
2015-08-07T07:02:29.588019+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=gentle-mesa-xxxx.herokuapp.com request
_id=97a466fd-b315-42d8-8976-7829e19cc778 fwd="79.41.230.143" dyno= connect= serv
ice= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: Are you trying to run a Swing chess game on Heroku?

Comment: @Kayaman yes, it's a small swing application

Comment: That's not how webapps work. The program is running on the server, which has no display. Even if it were to work, the frame would be shown on the server, not on your computer. You're trying to use Heroku wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The application you are trying to run is a GUI-based app (Graphical User Interface). This won't work on a remote server (which is "headless").